# mongoDB working set size when queries are getXbyId

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I'm trying to figure out the risks of performance reduction before adding a new collection to my mongo db.

my collection saves a byte array (5MB) for each document.

If i have lots of documents (N) does my working set considered to be = N * 5MB?

Bear in mind i use only one query for this collection:

getEntryByID (id)

and my collection is indexed at the id field.

does getById working set is reduced somewhat?

Comment: Does this answer you question: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/storage/#what-is-the-working-set?

Comment: Use collection stats to get a decent approximation of working set: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/collStats/ there's overhead in every collection, documents may be padded, indexes need space, .... So, your math is a rough but reasonable approximation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate the future database size in Mongo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617668/how-to-calculate-the-future-database-size-in-mongo)